# Synchronizing on an object, clarification needed

Tags: java, synchronization

If the goal here is to make sure that while List is being serialized and written to file, no changes are made to the it, what method does a better job?

```
private void save() throws IOException {
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(f);
    synchronized (list_of_important_data) {
        FileManipulationUtils.writeObject(list_of_important_stuff, MY_FILE);
    }
}

private void synchronized save() throws IOException {
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(f);
    FileManipulationUtils.writeObject(list_of_important_stuff, MY_FILE);
}
```

Do they both do the same thing for the purposes described? Is one better then the other?

Comment: I am not too clear on this but I guess the first one *might* be more efficient since it is synchronised for a shorter time? Difference depends on how long `deleteQuietly` takes and if it needs to be synced.

Comment: Do both ultimately do the same thing? Is one preferred over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't do the same thing at all.

The first synchronizes on the list; the second on the object you called save() on. As they synchronize on different objects, they defend against different concurrency races.

The first protects against mutation of the list while it is being saved, provided all mutation functions/accesses are likewise synchronized.

The second protects against save() being executed concurrently with itself, or (more importantly) any other method synchronized on the saved object.

Asking which is better than the other isn't sensible. They don't even remotely do the same thing, and therefore are not remotely comparable. Which one is best is going to depend on exactly what you are trying to achieve by synchronizing in the first place.

Given the confusion in your question, I suspect the answer might well be 'none-of-the-above', and in fact you need to rethink your concurrency design. To help with that, we will need to see more of your code, and have a better idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There is  anon-synchronization issue I wanted to raise. What is the relationship between 'deleteQuietly(f)' and MY_FILE? If they are related as I suspect, then any failure between delete, and write will lose your user's data. Stewart Smith, one of the mysql maintainers did a presentation on this and other IO issues at LCA 2007. I strongly recommend the video: http://lca2007.linux.org.au/talk/278.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void synchronized save() throws IOException {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(f);
        FileManipulationUtils.writeObject(list_of_important_stuff, MY_FILE);
    }
```

is same as

```
    private void save() throws IOException {
        synchronized(this){
            FileUtils.deleteQuietly(f);
            FileManipulationUtils.writeObject(list_of_important_stuff, MY_FILE);
        }
    }
```

choose a lock-shorter one